# Cordova Plugin Result return to Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, angular, visual-studio-code

I am writing a program in Angular that will be housed in a Cordova project. So this angular project is using one of the plugin that the community is sharing: https://github.com/mjwheatley/cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth

With this plugin, i am able to retrieve the device information fingerprint information in cordova plugin. But it does not allow me to store the information to my angular program. It will prompt the error or undefined when doing a direct storing to the global variable or returning the value back to the caller function respectively.

I have been sourcing for reference code to help on the bridging this plugin result to the global variable, but in vain. So is it possible to do bridging of the result to global variable?

And how to do it? I am not looking for a definite result, i just need some sample code to retrieve this plugin result in my main program.

Comment: After adding the plugin, the variable `window.FingerprintAuth` should exists in your application

Comment: Thanks. yes. it works but the plugin does not have a return value if i put it in a success callback method, but if i put the method line by line in the plugin method, it works.

But it make the plugin repeating in every page that I require it.

Comment: We are going to need to see some code :)